# How to combine an EventHandler with a SignalR hub with .NET core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

Using .NET Core 2.1, where I have a service like this:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    public event EventHandler<OrderUpdatedEvent> OrderUpdatedEventHandler; 

    ...
}
```

I also created a SignalR hub like this:

```
public class OrderHub : Hub
{
    private OrderService _orderService;
    private EventHandler<OrderUpdatedEvent> _eventHandler;

    public OrderHub(OrderService orderService)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OrderHub created...");
        _orderService = orderService;
        _eventHandler = (sender, updateEvent) => { SendUpdateOverWebsocket(updateEvent); };
        _orderService.OrderEventHandler += _eventHandler;
        Console.WriteLine("Event handler added!");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        _orderService.OrderUpdatedEventHandler -= _eventHandler;
    }
```

In the `OrderService` I have this line:

```
OrderUpdatedEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new OrderUpdatedEvent(orderId, ...));
```

The problem is that `OrderUpdatedEventHandler` is always `null` because the constructor of `OrderHub` does not seem to be created at application startup.

The `OrderService` is registered as singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOrderService, OrderService>();
```

I did find in the docs that .NET will only create singletons when it is "used". Which I understood as "a controller that has a dependency on this singleton is hit for the first time via a HTTP REST call".

What is also not good in my code is that `OrderHub` declares the constructor DI parameter as `OrderService` instead of `IOrderService`. I could probably get around it by directly injecting the hub into my `OrderService`, but I want to use events to have a loose coupling between the service and putting stuff on a websocket when something changes.

Answer (score 3):

As you already feared, the `OrderHub` is not created at application startup. The Hub will be created, when a client connects or invokes a method on the Hub. Another problem is, that the Hub gets directly disposed after the client has connected or a hub method has been invoked. So in your case, the Hub will immediately unsubscribe from the EventHandler. In addition the Hub instance is no singleton.

I would suggest the following solution, when your primary goal is loose coupling:

Create a `IOrderBroadcaster` interface, to be able to change the implementation from SignalR to another technology later:

```
public interface IOrderBroadcaster
{
    Task SendUpdate(string order);
}
```

The implementation for the SignalR version would look like that:

```
public class WebSocketOrderBroadcaster : IOrderBroadcaster
{
    private IHubContext<OrderHub> orderHubContext;

    public WebSocketOrderBroadcaster(IHubContext<OrderHub> orderHubContext)
    {
        this.orderHubContext = orderHubContext;
    }

    public Task SendUpdate(string order)
    {
        return this.orderHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Update", order);
    }
}
```

Also take care, that the new broadcaster is registered for DI in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOrderBroadcaster, WebSocketOrderBroadcaster>();
```

For this solution your `Hub` can remain empty:

```
public class OrderHub : Hub
{
}
```

In your `OrderService` you then can inject the IOrderBroadcaster and call your update method:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    private IOrderBroadcaster broadcaster;

    public OrderService(IOrderBroadcaster broadcaster)
    {
        this.broadcaster = broadcaster;
    }

    public void UpdateOrder(string order)
    {
        this.broadcaster.SendUpdate(order);
    }
}
```

With this solution you have achieved a loose coupling and also don't need EventHandlers, which should be avoided anyway in my opinion, when it's possible.

Happy coding!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why EventHandlers should be avoided? I come from a Java/Spring background where this is used a lot (https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

Comment: I'd make a Singleton not scoped

Comment: In the .NET world EventHandlers are also used a lot. Maybe it's more of a personal preference, but with EventHandlers you need to take care of certain things, like proper registration/deregistration to not run into memory leaks for example. This also applies for other languages like Java, JavaScript, etc. So I think it's better to use other paradigms, when it's possible.